# Should I use "with" in the following sentence?

Tags: sentence-construction, ellipsis

> Back in his room, he ambles to the desk and, with the same care he
> took me out (with), he places me in my dear home.

Is "with" necessary in this example? Second question, can I write: "with the same care as he took me out?"

Comment: This is an odd sentence. Is 'me' a person or an object? Strictly speaking it should be _with the same care with which he took me out_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second *which* in the original version of the sentence is at best redundant. Stylistically, it's strange to repeat *with* when it's not needed. The first *with* is required, but the second is not.

The suggested revision is also not entirely natural.

If it were me, I would rephrase the sentence to avoid the issue:

> Back in his room, he ambles to the desk and, with the same care he ***had*** **used to** ***take*** me out, he places me **back** in my dear home.